# Using DOM events in nodeJS and express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to catch a DOM event with nodeJS and express.
I have read something about "socket.io" module but I'm not able to use it correctly.

I'm trying to execute some code when when a "file input" changes it's content in the DOM.

```
<div class="input-group">
 <div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input form-control" id="inputGroupFile02"
   aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var socket = io();;
    $( "#inputGroupFileAddon02" ).change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('cambio_imagen_profile_edit', "Cambiando la imagen");
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my express server configuration, it's correct the socket.io configuration?:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require("http");
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4001);

httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), () =>
    console.log('Inicializando servidor en el puerto ', app.get('port'), ' !!!')
)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket connected');
    socket.on('cambio_imagen_profile_edit', (msg) => {
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
  });
```

I need to make an "on change" event on "inputGroupFile02" element.
Someone knows about it?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

On the backend side you have to define the event handlers for incoming messages from the sockets.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer );

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    // handle the msg here
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

And add the event on the frontend side that will send information about the change of the input element

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $("#inputGroupFile02").change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('cambio_imagen_profile_edit', "Cambiando la imagen");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just modify the function so it broadcast the information you want backend server to receive and call it onChange event

Comment: I changed the code with my try, do you know what's happening? Thanks! @Krzysztof Krzeszewski

Comment: what do you expect to happen? what's the output of the console on the backend and frontend? did you try using the upload function?

Comment: i think i know what you did wrong, to the `io` constructor you have to pass httpServer not the `http` module, also the selector for jQuery is wrong, you meant to use the id, but used the other parameter instead, as much as i'd advise against using jquery I've edited my answer to accommodate you using it